# Dynamically including an XML relative layout multiple times in a parent view

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I have an XML RelativeLayout snippet that I would like to include several times (from a loop) in my main View. The problem seems to be -- is there a way to avoid hard-coding the parent of the RatingBar, since each time I include the RelativeLayout snippet my elements will need to have different ids?

As far as I can tell, the recommended way is to get the layout snippet and then override the android:id for each element to be unique, and then override the android:layout_below manually for each element that has relative positioning. This seems a little kludgy -- is there any way to have these bindings get done automatically?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" 
    android:id="@+id/relativeView">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:text="Label"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/ratingBar1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/textView1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need to change the id of the `RelativeLayout`
like

```
int BASEID=200;

View v = mLayoutInflator.inflate(R.layout.myRelativeLayout, null);

for (int i;i<10;i++){
    v.findViewById(R.id.relativeView).setId(i+BASEID);
}

mRootView.addView(v,...);
```

then when you need to get the `RatingBar` for suppose the 4th `RelativeLayout` you added you can call

```
RatingBar mRatingBar = (RatingBar)mRootView.findViewById(BASEID+3).findViewById(R.id.ratingBar1);
```

Comment: Thanks -- I ended up driving the number of elements off of a list of strings, so I just set the tag on each element to the string value, which worked well. Same idea though.